# Change json object data by reference in Python

Tags: python, json, mongodb, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have implemented one application which stores data in mongodb format. I have 10k records as like below format in my collections.

Now, I would like to change the format of json data as described below.

I would like to change mainly below things :

1) TimeStamp attribute :

```
{
    "timestamp": {
        "$numberLong": "1442888576971"
    },
    "checked": false,
    "details": "abc def",
    "text": "Other (I,SU,S)"
}
```

to

```
{
    "timestamp": "1442888576971",
    "checked": false,
    "details": "abc def",
    "text": "Other (I,SU,S)"
}
```

2)

```
"decision": {
    "$numberLong": "1"
},
"condition": {
    "$numberLong": "5"
}
```

to

```
"decision": "1",
"condition": "5"
```

**Input json**

```
  {
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "5600baac79a89d0b0c9cfb6f"
        },
        "appData": {
            "99390": {
                "ABC": {
                    "trackeddata": [
                        {
                            "timestamp": {
                                "$numberLong": "1442888576971"
                            },
                            "checked": false,
                            "details": "abc def",
                            "text": "Other (I,SU,S)"
                        },
                        {
                            "timestamp": {
                                "$numberLong": "1442888578443"
                            },
                            "checked": false,
                            "details": "eft ghjy",
                            "text": "A (I,S)"
                        }
                    ],
                    "selecteddata": [
                        {
                            "checked": false,
                            "details": "abc def",
                            "text": "A (I,S)"
                        }
                    ],
                    "iconData": [
                        {
                            "timestamp": {
                                "$numberLong": "1442888573233"
                            },
                            "c1": "yellow",
                            "c2": "yellow",
                            "c3": "red"
                        },
                        {
                            "timestamp": {
                                "$numberLong": "1442888576972"
                            },
                            "c1": "yellow",
                            "c2": "yellow",
                            "c3": "yellow"
                        }
                    ],
                    "decision": {
                        "$numberLong": "1"
                    },
                    "condition": {
                        "$numberLong": "5"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I wrote below code, but in this code I can change thing locally only. I can not able to change data in main json object by reference so I do not need to compute too much.

Is there any efficient way to change above two things in whole file in very fast way.

This below code not completely working. I left it because I think so this is not really efficient algorithm.

**Here is my code :**

```
import json

with open("t2.json") as json_file:
    json_data = json.load(json_file)
    userset = set([])
    userList = [];
    userDict = {};
    for i in json_data:
        innerdata =  i['appData']
        for key, value in innerdata.items():
            for key1,value1 in value.items():
                innerdata2 = value1['trackeddata'];
                if innerdata2:
                    for item in innerdata2:
                        print item;
                        if type(item) is dict:
                            for k1,v1 in item.items():
                                timedata = item['timestamp']
                                epochtime = "";
                                for k2,v2 in timedata.items():
                                    epochtime = timedata['$numberLong']
                                    print epochtime;
                                item['timestamp'] = epochtime;
                                print item['timestamp'];
                                print type(item['timestamp']);
            if not userDict.has_key(key):
                userDict[key] = [value];
            else:
                userDict[key].append(value)
            userList.append(key);
    #print userList;
    my_set = set(userList)
    with open('result.json', 'w') as fp:
        json.dump(userDict, fp)
```

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop through each key in the `ABC` array then set the value for `timestamp` if the key is in `['trackedata', 'iconData']` or in  `['condition', 'decision']`

```
>>> import json
>>> with open('input.json') as inf, \
...      open('output.json', 'w') as outf:
...     init_data = json.load(inf)
...     appData = init_data['appData']
...     for key in appData:
...         abc = appData[key]['ABC']
...         for subkeys in abc:
...             if subkeys in ['condition', 'decision']:
...                 abc[subkeys] = abc[subkeys]['$numberLong']
...             if subkeys in ['trackeddata', 'iconData']:
...                 for element in abc[subkeys]:
...                     element['timestamp'] = element['timestamp']['$numberLong']
...     json.dump(init_data, outf)
...
```

Your output.json look like this:

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(init_data)
{'_id': {'$oid': '5600baac79a89d0b0c9cfb6f'},
 'appData': {'99390': {'ABC': {'condition': '5',
                               'decision': '1',
                               'iconData': [{'c1': 'yellow',
                                             'c2': 'yellow',
                                             'c3': 'red',
                                             'timestamp': '1442888573233'},
                                            {'c1': 'yellow',
                                             'c2': 'yellow',
                                             'c3': 'yellow',
                                             'timestamp': '1442888576972'}],
                               'selecteddata': [{'checked': False,
                                                 'details': 'abc def',
                                                 'text': 'A (I,S)'}],
                               'trackeddata': [{'checked': False,
                                                'details': 'abc def',
                                                'text': 'Other (I,SU,S)',
                                                'timestamp': '1442888576971'},
                                               {'checked': False,
                                                'details': 'eft ghjy',
                                                'text': 'A (I,S)',
                                                'timestamp': '1442888578443'}]}}}}
>>>
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91946/discussion-between-user3100115-and-sam-k).